A common technique in number theory to evaluate integration
Sorry this question is a bit weird ...
I saw a technique in some number theory book (that I don't remember the name - I checked Titchmarsh but I couldn't find) that in order to evaluate some integral (or sum?) from 0 to X, the author divides [0,X] into ..., $[X/2^n, X/2^{n-1}], ..., [X/2,X]$ and at the end multiplies the result of integration on [X/2,X] by I think $\log X$.
I searched for the explanation and I found on MSE that it is a famous technique and one had a post on it with an answer. But I can't find that post! I can't find the book that I studied in! I searched a lot, "dyadic partition to evaluate integral" is one of many but still I couldn't find it. I am sure it is something very common in number theory otherwise I wouldn't have asked with this extent of vagueness. Please help if you know about this technique or the link for OP in MSE, thanks!

I know it as dyadic decomposition

Calling this "dyadic summation" or "dyadic integration" or "dyadic decomposition" would all be understood.
I'll note that generically it is not necessary to add a log factor.
That is, if you can show that
$$ \int_{T/2}^{T} f(x) dx \ll T^\alpha \log^\beta T,$$
for some $\alpha > 0, \beta \geq 0$, then
$$\begin{align}\int_0^X f(x) dx &\ll \sum_{n \geq 0} \int_{T/2^{n+1}}^{T/2^n} f(x) dx
\ll \sum_{n} (T/2^n)^\alpha \log^\beta (T/2^n)
\\
&\ll \sum_{n} (T/2^n)^\alpha \log^\beta T
\ll T^\alpha \log^\beta T \sum_{n} 2^{-\alpha n}
\\ &\ll T^\alpha \log^\beta T
.\end{align}$$
The only cost is that the implicit constant at the end is in principle larger than the implicit constant in the original bound.

This is a fundamental tool. I looked at a few of my most recent preprints to see what I call it.

In one, I don't use it (go figure).
In counting divisors, I call it "dyadic partition" (and use it for summation).
In sums of cusp forms, I call it "dyadic subdivision" for an integration, and sums over "dyadic subintervals" for a summation, and "dyadic summation" for a later summation.
In murmurations, I use the functionally similar tool of using a partition of unity (but not using a dyadic partition of unity). In a preprint that I'll post probably in the next two weeks that follows up on this paper, I do use a dyadic partition of unity. These achieve the same goal.

